# Fortigate 30E logs to VMware ubuntu logstash server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, fortigate

I need a bit of help from those wiser.

I've built a virtual machine log server that runs on Ubuntu. The log server has an ELK stack installed through which logs from other virtual machines (normal Ubuntu and Windows Server) are already passing. The problem is that I can't get any logs from FortiGate into Logstash on the log server; the /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log file doesn't show any information about the FortiGate logs. I have set the virtual machine's IP address and the port 5144, which I use in the Logstash configuration file, from the firewall's management panel. I've also modified the virtual machine's NAT port forwarding settings. I wonder where the problem might be and where I could ask for help.

[portforwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VovUJ.png)

Comment: Can you please share your Logstash configuration file for us to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: @MuratK. Currently conf file looks like this, i have another pipeline that goes input / beats 5044. input {
  udp {
    host => "192.168.138.140"
    port => 5144
  }
}

filter {

}

output {
  stdout {}
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.